# Python problem I only got 1 output every user input and not combined with the previous input

Tags: python

How I can achieve this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJVRS.jpg)

Comment: while True:
 ask = (input("Enter a number: "))
 l = ask.split()
 print(sorted(l))

Comment: Please provide the expected see [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
Off-site links and images of text are not acceptable; your posting must be self-contained, in keeping with the purpose of this site.

Comment: Critical updates must be edited into your question, not relegated to comments.

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

Create a List variable and append each Input in the variable. Something like that

```
a = []
a.append(int(input("Enter Message")))
print(a)
```

Comment: I've only getting this output.                     
 Enter a number: 12
[12]
Enter a number: 54
[54]
Enter a number: 76
[76]

Comment: Have you initialize a with list? like a= [] .For me it is working fine. I am on python 3.8

>>> a
[12, 13]
>>> a.append(int(input("Enter Message")))
Enter Message11
>>> a.append(int(input("Enter Message")))
Enter Message15
>>> a
[12, 13, 11, 15]
>>>

Comment: to clarify, the list must be initialized outside of the loop

Answer (score 0):

```py
inputs = []  # create an empty list
while True:  # loop forever
    inp = input("Enter a number or...")  # take user input
    if inp == "":  # if the user simply pressed enter the input would be empty
        break  # exit the loop
    inputs.append(int(inp))  # add the input to the list of inputs
    print(inputs)  # display the current list of inputs
print("Exiting")  # after the loop
```